# R Making Histograms with Equal Widths and # Of Breaks

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm been having trouble making the plots of my R graph have equal widths and # of breaks.

Currently, I have

```
hist(result1,xlim=c(2,4),breaks=10)
abline(v=pi,col="red")
hist(result2,xlim=c(2,4),breaks=10)
```

I am trying to jutapose 2 graphs on top of each other with the same axis # of bars and same width of bars.

The odd thing is that when I set breaks = 10, the top graph will occasionally have more bars than the bottom and their widths are not equal. Am I not understanding the breaks parameter correctly?

[image]

Comment: This is SO at it's best: Among your answers you have one using base graphics, one using ggplot2, and one using ggplot2 in a more sophisticated manner.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you are plotting the two histograms on top of each other with:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
```

For the fixed breaks I would suggest:

```
bins <- seq(2, 4, by=0.1)

hist(results1, breaks=bins, xlim=c(2,4))
hist(results2, breaks=bins, xlim=c(2,4))
```

Answer (score 3):

I think using `ggplot2` facetting is great for this kind of plots. Let's create some data:

```
carat1 = diamonds
carat1$id = "one"
carat2 = diamonds
carat2$id = "two"
carat2 = within(carat2, { carat = carat * 1000 })
carat_comb = rbind(carat1, carat2)
```

Let's make a plot:

```
ggplot(aes(x = carat), data = carat_comb) + 
    geom_histogram() + facet_wrap(~ id, ncol = 1)
```

[image]

To make this plot work when the x-axis is quite different is to tell ggplot that the axis values can be determined independently:

```
ggplot(aes(x = carat), data = carat_comb) + geom_histogram() + 
    facet_wrap(~ id, ncol = 1, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've always found the issue you describe tricky to deal with too, and in general if your data is very different you might not be able to do what you want.  Even so, you might have better luck using the `ggplot2` graphics version:

```
library('ggplot2')
qplot(x = carat, data = diamonds, geom = "histogram", binwidth = 0.1)
```

If this approach will work for you, you can do the following to get two plots, one above the other:

```
library('grid')
a <- qplot(x = carat, data = diamonds, geom = "histogram", binwidth = 0.1)
b <- qplot(x = carat, data = diamonds, geom = "histogram", binwidth = 0.1)

vplayout <- function(x, y) viewport(layout.pos.row = x, layout.pos.col = y)
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(2, 1)))
print(a, vp = vplayout(1,1))
print(b, vp = vplayout(2,1))
```